# List items from MySQL DB to PHP Site

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I'm trying to list down all the emails that a specific user have referred in our site so they can have a track record of the users they've confirmed as their referral.

My `referrer` table is composed of 4 columns.

```
Id | user_id | user_email | referrer_email
```

If I am the referrer. When I go to my profile page, I'll have a list of `user_email`s that has my email as `referrer_email` in them.

My question is how can I perform an `echo` to display the emails that a user has referred? Currently, it doesn't show the emails that it should in my site.

Here's what I currently have.

```
<?php
$referredlist = db_getrow("SELECT user_email FROM referrer WHERE referrer_email =".$userrow['user_email'], $global_connection);
?>
<tr><td valign=top align=center>
<div class="profilecolumn" style='float:left;'>
<a id='btnprofile' class="profilebutton" href='' style='background-color: #8DBF3F; color: white;' onclick='return showsection("profile");'>Profile</a>
<a id='btntrans' class="profilebutton" href=''  onclick='return showsection("trans");'>Completed Transactions</a>
<h4 class='orange' style='text-align:left;'>Confirmed Referrals</span></h4><br><br>
<?php foreach($referredlist as $key -> $val){ ?> 

<h4><?php echo $val; ?></h4>

<?php
}
?>
```

I also have this.

```
<?php
$global_connection = db_connect();

if ($global_connection) {
    $curuserid = util_getuserid();

    if (isset($_REQUEST['member']))
        $userrow = db_getrow("select * from user where user_id=".$_REQUEST['member'], $global_connection);
    else
        $userrow = array();

    if (count($userrow)) {
        $pagetitle = $userrow['user_login']." Lookingfour Profile";
        if ($userrow['user_id'] == $curuserid)
            $pagetitle = "My Lookingfour Profile";

?>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Edited the post. Sorry about that. Thank you

Comment: I tried to do some code formatting for your code and noticed that your code is incomplete at many places... you're opening HTML tags and they are never closed, same with brackets... you open a `h4`-tag and close a `span` at the end.
Please clean up your Code before asking questions!

Comment: @Sergej Thanks for that! This is only a snippet of the code that concerns the php part which is in question that's why it lacks some codes.

Comment: you should always try to ask with working code, because it's easier to help you if the code is clear ;-)

Comment: Thanks but was thinking it is a huge pile of codes to display in here thats why I've just copied the concerned part. Will try and paste the whole code. Thanks @Sergej

Comment: not whole, just working ;-) you also could remove things like the CSS in your code because it is unnecessary

Comment: This is working code. However, it shows "Array" in front-end instead of the list of emails. @Sergej

Comment: Updated. Now it shows nothing. Added a foreach loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT user_emails FROM referrer WHERE referrer_email = 'YOUR_EMAIL';
```

Comma separated emails:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_emails) as emails FROM referrer WHERE referrer_email = 'YOUR_EMAIL';
```

this will output as: email1,email2,etc..

here `YOUR_EMAIL` means logged in user's email

Comment: Hi @noddy! Should I use these codes and assign to a variable and echo where I want to place it?

Comment: Hi @noddy! Tried to assign it in a variable and echoed the variable but on the front-end of my site it showed "Array" instead of displaying a list of emails.

Comment: Or you can var_dump(VARIABLENAME);

Comment: Tried var_dump(variable) and from "Array" it showed "array(0) { }"

I've edited my post to show the codes.

Comment: $userrow = db_getrow("select * from user where user_id=".$_REQUEST['member'], $global_connection);